# Click all buttons on page with same class Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to click all buttons on a page with the `class` `"btn btn-primary UnFollowUser"`.

Here is the script I have tried using

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName('UnFollowUser');

for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
   buttons[i].click();
```

But that throws the error:

> VM336:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of
>   undefined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM336:5InjectedScript._evaluateOn @
>   VM158:878InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @
>   VM158:811InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM158:667

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean `getElementsByClassName('UnFollowUser');`

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: @itsgoingdown ah, that fixed it!

Answer (score 12):

You are using getElementsByName instead of `getElementsByClassName`

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('UnFollowUser');

 for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  
     buttons[i].click();
```

Comment: Do you see any mention of jQuery in the question? You don't even mention it in your answer.

Comment: Anything for instagram massunfollow all? how we can unfollow all of them at once?

Comment: @Kain the for is wrong, it should be `(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) `

Comment: what if after clicked the button the class _UnFollowUser_ is removed ? the length of the object will change.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error for some reason (and yes I was using getElementsByClassName). For some reason using a "while (buttons.length != 0)" instead of a "for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)" fixed the issue.

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('nameOfClass');

 while(buttons.length != 0)  
     buttons[i].click();
```

I believe the reason why this worked is that for some reason the button's array updated each time a button was destroyed: so when the loop is on the 5th of 5 buttons, i = 5, but buttons.length = 5 so it would terminate prematurely.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a working code example and explain why this doesn't create an endless loop.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thanks! Made the changes.